# Integral of real part of $z$ around the unit circle

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration, analyticity, analytic-functions

[image: question 1]

Q 32 If C denotes the counterclockwise unit circle, the value of the contour integral is

What is the result of integrating the real part of z (a complex number) anti clockwise around the unit circle?

At first glance, I couldn't identify any points within the circle where analyticity  breaks down. So it seemed to me that the integral should vanish and the answer should be 0. Since the real part of a complex number is differentiable everywhere right? It seems smooth.

But I tried using parameterization and got the answer to be i$\pi$. So I am guessing there is a residue of 0.5 at 0 maybe?

[image: my attempt]

So my question is, can we use Cauchy residue theorem to solve this? If so how? Is there a more elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: That’s the right answer, by a correct method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real part of $z$ is not a complex-differentiable function anywhere. So, what can we do instead in order to apply complex analysis techniques? We can find an analytic function that agrees with it on the circle - even if it's completely different everywhere else.

First, we note that $\text{Re}(z) = \frac12(z+\overline{z})$. Since the conjugate isn't analytic, that isn't good enough yet. But then, for $|z|=1$, $\overline{z}=\frac1z$. So, on the circle $|z|=1$ we care about,
$$\text{Re}(z) = \frac12\left(z+\frac1z\right)$$
That's something we can work with. (Of course, it's a bit absurd to apply the residue theorem to the literal integral $\frac az$ around a circle - we needed that integral to prove the theorem in the first place)

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I wanted.

Comment: +1 , i was searching for the perfect solution and here it is.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle{1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos t \ ie^{it} dt = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} {1 \over 2 } (e^{it} + e^{-it}) \ e^{it} dt = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Not true - $dz$ isn't real.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: That was embarrassing.

Comment: Here $dz = ie^{it}$ right? And we can write $Re(z) = \cos t = \frac{(e^{it}+ e^{-it})}{2} $ all of this makes sense. So we have $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{2it} + 1 = 2\pi$ because $\cos 0 = \cos 2\pi$. So I don't see why this is wrong just because $dz$ is not real? This is almost the same way I solved it above in the question details, like I did via the trigonometric route, it was much longer. This is super fast. Isn't this correct too?

Comment: I edited out my embarrassing mistake. The answer above is correct. For real measures we have $\operatorname{re} (\int f d \mu) = \int \operatorname{re}(f)  d \mu$, but that does not apply here.

Comment: Generally I find using the exponential to be more convenient than trigonometric functions.

Comment: My original comment applied to the pre-edit version of this answer, which was different and wrong. The revised version is clean and correct.

Comment: Oh ok, got it the real part of a complex integral of $f(z)$ is same as the complex integral of the real part of $f(z)$ if we integrate over the real line? is that what real measures mean? Here our path is complex so it does not apply right? Thanks anyway, I guess I need to study measure theory to really understand this.

Comment: It doesn't take measure theory - just the definition of a line integral. $\int_C f(z)\,dz$ is defined as $\int_a^b f(z(t))\cdot z'(t)\,dt$ for a parametrization $z(t)$ of the curve. When is taking the real part of the integral the same as taking the real part of $f$? When that tangent $z'(t)$ is real - when the curve is just a line parallel to the real axis. Otherwise, the real part of $f\cdot z'$ will mix information from real and imaginary parts of $f$.